# Ambiguous solution involving radicals

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

Evaluating the expression: $$\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}+ \sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}} $$

So my solution involves rewriting the expression inside the bigger radical signs as perfect squares: $$\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2} \right)^2}+ \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2} \right)^2} $$

From which I then get $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2} = 2\sqrt{3} $. However we can also write the original expression as $$\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} \right)^2}+ \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3} \right)^2} $$ and from this get $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3} = 2\sqrt{2} $.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is the non-negative real number $t$ such that $t^2=x$, therefore $\sqrt{(\sqrt 2-\sqrt3)^2}\ne\sqrt2-\sqrt 3<0$.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ so $\sqrt{(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})^2}=|\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}|=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}\,$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thanks